# Avoiding reinterpret_cast when accessing raw data

Tags: c++

I'm working on a function accessing pixel data, which can be available in different formats, e.g. 8 bit and 16 bit monochrome. The memory block is given as an `std::span<uint8_t>` always (as memory management is byte based).

The existing code looks like this right now (simplified):

```cpp
void foo(std::span<uint8_t> pixels, PixelFormat format)
{
    switch (format) {
    case PixelFormat::Monochrome8bit:
        bar<unit8_t>(pixels);
        break;
    case PixelFormat::Monochrome16bit:
        bar<unit16_t>({reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(pixels.data()), pixels.size() / sizeof(unit16_t)});
        break;
    }
}
```

So at some point I must convert the 8 bit pointers to 16 bit pointers (assuming byte order is not an issue). But Clang-Tidy gives me a warning "Do not use reinterpret_cast". Using templates for the underlying data management is not an option. So how should I deal with that? Is there a better way with C++20 than just suppressing said warning?

Comment: This is endian sensitive. Proper way would be write code which is endian independent. What this `bar` do? Maybe it should accept `uint8_t*` and just do `result[i]= in[2*i] + (in[2*i + 1] << 8u);` and let optimizer decide if simple copy can be done,

Comment: I know (that's why I said "assuming byte order is not an issue"). Usually the data already was converted properly in case that's necessary (e.g. when reading from a file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre `C++20` there is only one legal way to access an array of bytes as some type of unrelated POD, which is `memcpy`. In `C++20` there is also `bit_cast` to access the bytes in one type as some other unrelated type.

If you want to interpret a span of bytes depending on some run time variable, you can use templates, but you have to to the conversion inside the template, not before.

All instantiations must take the span of bytes as an argument. And only when you access each element in the memory, you interpret as the correct type.

```
template<class T> void bar(span<uint8_t> pixels);

void foo(std::span<uint8_t> pixels, PixelFormat format)
{
    switch (format) {
    case PixelFormat::Monochrome8bit:
        bar<unit8_t>(pixels);
        break;
    case PixelFormat::Monochrome16bit:
        bar<unit16_t>(pixels);
        break;
    }
}

template<class T> void bar(span<uint8_t> pixels)
{
    const size_t pixel_count = (pixels.size() / sizeof(T));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pixel_count; ++i) {
         uint8_t* src = pixels.data() + i*sizeof(T);
         T pixel;
         std::memcpy(&pixel, src, sizeof(T));

         // use pixel for something
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing out `bit_cast`. I think I like to avoid `memcpy`, so I guess I will try to minimize `reinterpret_cast` usage, maybe only once in a template method `std::span<T> as()` as part of the class providing the data.

Comment: Note that using `reinterpret_cast` in this manner is technically undefined behavior and should be avoided, unless every single compiler and their versions you ever will compile this code with explicitly defines this behavior in the way you expect.

Comment: Would `static_cast<uint16_t*>(static_cast<void*>(p))` also be undefined behavior, assuming `p` points to the data of a `std::vector<uint8_t>` containing the lower and upper bytes of the 16 bit values in the right order?

Comment: That is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`, so yes, that is also undefined behavior.

Comment: I see. My problem is, that for performance reasons I cannot afford to `memcpy` the whole `span`, which might take several megabytes, but the interface of my `bar` method should really accept a `span<uint16_t>`, not a `span<uint8_t>`. I guess I must live with the fact, that only some specific platforms are supported, maybe with a fallback using `memcpy` for other ones. Thank you for your help.